# Yoast's WordPress SEO plugin is not showing the correct snippet

Tags: plugin-wp-seo-yoast

I am facing a problem. I am not getting the snippet which YOAST plugin showed me. The snippet in Google search is different from what YOAST is showing. Check out the screenshots ([http://imgur.com/a/ko5lQ](https://imgur.com/a/ko5lQ)). Let me know what is the solution of it?

Comment: How long has it been since you set it in WP SEO?

Comment: This question might be Plugin-specific enough to direct [to the Plugin developer himself](http://wordpress.org/tags/wordpress-seo?forum_id=10).

Comment: @m0r7if3r: 7 days.

Comment: Have you seen any of your other changes get implemented, ie: is it just the description that's missing, or has the rest failed to take too?

Comment: Other problem is that I am getting my tags in google search result whereas I have mentioned in YOAST not to index tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is suppose to work this way.
Joost's plugin only gives you a great tool for you to optimize your snippet.

If you haven't done any optimizations whatsoever, like creating an awesome brief description of what your content is all about, Google will probably try to figure out what's the best bit of content by their own.

Just a minor edit, Google just released a video exactly replying your question: http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=35624

Answer (score 0):

Try getting google to recrawl your site, they only come by every so often and update their info then. You can do this with google webmaster tools if you have that setup, I'm sure there are other methods, but I don't know of them.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise signing up for Google Webmaster Tools if you haven't already (easy to verify ownership of site with Yoast's plugin). They offer advice on topics like this and recommend NOT repeating the same meta description for every page. Google always reserves the right to change the snippet depending on your page or the keyword phrase being searched.

Comment: +1 on Google Webmaster Tools of course. But looking at the screenshot, this isn't exactly the case. OK, I might have been a bit harsh with my statement, but unlike other plugins, Joost's plugin actually gives you a pretty awesome way to **craft** your snippet _per post_.

Comment: I have already signed up to Google Webmaster. I have verified my site on Google, Alexa, Bing etc. Everything is fine. It is just that the snippet output was different.